# Deeplearning4j org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4jBackend$NoAvailableBackendException

Tags: java, neural-network, deeplearning4j

I cannot run a simple program that I wrote to start understanding Deeplearning4j.

I tried the code from this link:
[Deep Learning In Java Using Deeplearning4J](https://www.baeldung.com/deeplearning4j)

unfortunately it didn't work for me. In fact I have this error:

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
>   See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
>   details. Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError     at
>   org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.convertWritables(RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.java:377)
>     at
>   org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.convertFeaturesOrLabels(RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.java:271)
>     at
>   org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.nextMultiDataSet(RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.java:234)
>     at
>   org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.next(RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.java:177)
>     at
>   org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderDataSetIterator.next(RecordReaderDataSetIterator.java:306)
>     at
>   org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderDataSetIterator.next(RecordReaderDataSetIterator.java:393)
>     at
>   org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderDataSetIterator.next(RecordReaderDataSetIterator.java:51)
>     at com.alessio.text.App.main(App.java:38) Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4jBackend$NoAvailableBackendException:
>   Please ensure that you have an nd4j backend on your classpath. Please
>   see: http://nd4j.org/getstarted.html  at
>   org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.initContext(Nd4j.java:6089)  at
>   org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.(Nd4j.java:201)  ... 8 more`enter
>   code here` Caused by:
>   org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4jBackend$NoAvailableBackendException:
>   Please ensure that you have an nd4j backend on your classpath. Please
>   see: http://nd4j.org/getstarted.html  at
>   org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4jBackend.load(Nd4jBackend.java:258)    at
>   org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.initContext(Nd4j.java:6086)  ... 9 more

I'll appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance

Comment: "See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder" just like the error says.  You have to have slf4j as one of your dependencies, but not having it simply supresses logging and should not affect your code.  Is there another exception?  Post your code.

Comment: Also: "Please ensure that you have an nd4j backend on your classpath. Please see: http://nd4j.org/getstarted.html"  What build system or IDE are you using, it seems your do not have your classpath setup correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the comments above: You need an nd4j backend. Please take a look at the error message. The documentation for that is right in that link. Usually you want nd4j-native-platform and the latest version. For the latest versions of things, please use our examples repo: https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples